# What happens at the end of the Vikram and Betal story?

Tags: history, vikramaditya

What happens at the end of Vikram and Betal story? I did some searching and I found [some info like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baital_Pachisi)

> Vetala Panchavimshati (Sanskrit: वेतालपञ्चविंशति, IAST: vetālapañcaviṃśati or Baital Pachisi (Bengali) ("Twenty-five (tales) of Baital"), is a collection of tales and legends within a frame story, from India. It was originally written in Sanskrit.

I just want to know what the end of the story is.

Comment: I'm not sure that questions about Vikram-and-Betaal are on-topic here - they're certainly _about_ Hindu people, but are the stories themselves related to Hinduism in any substantial sense?

Comment: @senshin Well, the people being Hindu isn't the only connection to Hinduism - the gods do play a role in the story.

Comment: @senshin you are the one who gave [answer as on-topic](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/107/93) :P.

Comment: @Mr_Green Do note that I was careful to specify that questions about Vikramaditya in a particular Purana ought to be on-topic. I don't really have a strong opinion on Vikram-Betaal, but my sense is that, as a piece of folklore, it falls somewhere in between questions that are obviously on topic (e.g. scripture) and questions that are obviously off-topic (e.g. straight-up history questions). It's been long enough since I read Vikram-Betaal that I don't really remember the details of the story, so I don't have a strong opinion about the on-topicness of this question... [cont.]

Comment: ...though @Keshav is of course right to note that there are divine elements to the story, which is a point in its favor.

Comment: This story is part of tales but how can we decide they are on topic or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vetaal explains to King Vikram aaditya the evil intentions of the tantrik who had asked king vikram to get vetaal for sacrifice. Eventually Vikram kills the tantrik frees vetaal with a wish that he will come to his aid when needed

Comment: Where did you find this? Could you please provide a source?

Comment: You should cite some sources.